# How to extract text inside a div tag using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, winforms, html-agility-pack

I want to extract the text "Some text goes here" between the div class.
I am using html agility pack, and c#

```
<div class="productDescriptionWrapper">
Some Text Goes here...
<div class="emptyClear"> </div>
</div>
```

this is what I have :

```
Description = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"productDescriptionWrapper\").Descendants("div").Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();
```

I get this error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

I know how to extract if the text is b/w a `<h1>` or `<p>` instead of "div" in Descendants i will have to give "h1" or "p".

Somebody please assist.

Comment: Where is the closing bracket of `[@class=\"productDescriptionWrapper\"`?

Comment: may be i missed it when i typed it here ... it doesnt work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes such as

`//div[@class='productDescriptionWrapper']`

to get all descendants of all types use:

`//div[@class='productDescriptionWrapper']//*`,

to get all descendants of a specific type 
such as a `p` then use `//div[@class='productDescriptionWrapper']//p`.

to get all descendants that are either a `div` or a `p`:

```
//div[@class='productDescriptionWrapper']//*[self::div or self::p]
```

say you wanted to get all non blank descendant text nodes then use:

```
//div[@class='productDescriptionWrapper']//text()[normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get null reference exception given `doc` is created from HTML snippet you posted. Anyway, if you meant to get text within the outer `<div>`, but not from the inner one, then use xpath `/text()` which mean *get direct child text nodes*.

For example, given this HTML snippet :

```
var html = @"<div class=""productDescriptionWrapper"">
Some Text Goes here...
<div class=""emptyClear"">Don't get this one</div>
</div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

..this expression return text from the outer `<div>` only :

```
var Description = doc.DocumentNode
                     .SelectNodes("//div[@class='productDescriptionWrapper']/text()")
                     .Select(x => x.InnerText.Trim())
                     .First();
//Description : 
//"Some Text Goes here..."
```

..while in contrast, the following return all the text :

```
var Description = doc.DocumentNode
                     .SelectNodes("//div[@class='productDescriptionWrapper']")
                     .Select(x => x.InnerText.Trim())
                     .First();
//Description :
//"Some Text Goes here...
//Don't get this one"
```